# cannot store context object in database msbotframework nodejs

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created a bot and installed it to my microsoft teams. and I got conversation update event along with the contextObject.

```
/ Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        console.log(context);
        await bot.run(context);
    });
});
```

I want to store this context object for future reference. I tried storing it in postgress database of column type json. When I retrieve the context object from database and perform some actions like

```
 context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text('All messages have been sent.'));
```

it is throwing activity not found error

```
[onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: Missing activity on context
```

I want to store the context Object somewhere. or Is there any way that I can get the context object from "activity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at how to [send proactive notifications to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript).

In short; there are helper function to achieve your goal. First you retrieve the conversation reference.

```js
const conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);
```

Followed by the following snippet to continue a conversation, based on the saved actvity.

```js
await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
    // If you encounter permission-related errors when sending this message, see
    // https://aka.ms/BotTrustServiceUrl
    await turnContext.sendActivity('proactive hello');
});
```